# Pagination of UIViews on Screen - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to implement scrollable list of UIViews.

[image: ss]

As shown in screenshot above, there is 3 buttons shown on the screen. I am trying create a list of uiViews, that user can scroll them 3 at a time.

I have implemented this in **UICollection**. The problem is user can scroll freely throw items. I want him to be able to scroll 3 at a time.

Is it possible with **UICollection** or should I use another component ?

Comment: I think you need to create one parent view and add all three items or buttons into it and then you need to add that view in scrollview.

Comment: but the number will be dynamic, it can be 5, 6 or more. it depends on the server side what this user has permission to do. @AshokLondhe

Comment: That is fine. We can manage it. check what is count of we are getting dynamically. divide it by 3 and then add  that number of parentView . And then add 3 uiview in each parent view. share your code ... i will update it.

Comment: Please check my answer and try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to enable paging for the `UICollectionView`. Just check the box saying Paging Enabled in the attributes inspector. You can limit the number of cells to three by returning 1/3rd of the collectionview's width in the `sizeForItemAt` Flowlayout delegate method of the collectionview.

[image]

Comment: That was it ! :)